# C# loop to test internet connection

Tags: c#, wpf

Looking for the best loop to use and if I'm testing internet connection correctly or not.

loop ->

```
        do
        {
            OnlineStatus.Text = "Online";
            OnlineStatus.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255));
        } while (IsNetworkAvailable());
```

IsNetworkAvailable code

```
 public static bool IsNetworkAvailable()
    {
        return IsNetworkAvailable(0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether any network connection is available.
    /// Filter connections below a specified speed, as well as virtual network cards.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="minimumSpeed">The minimum speed required. Passing 0 will not filter connection using speed.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if a network connection is available; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public static bool IsNetworkAvailable(long minimumSpeed)
    {
        if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            return false;

        foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            // discard because of standard reasons
            if ((ni.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up) ||
                (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback) ||
                (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel))
                continue;

            // this allow to filter modems, serial, etc.
            // I use 10000000 as a minimum speed for most cases
            if (ni.Speed < minimumSpeed)
                continue;

            // discard virtual cards (virtual box, virtual pc, etc.)
            if ((ni.Description.IndexOf("virtual", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) ||
                (ni.Name.IndexOf("virtual", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
                continue;

            // discard "Microsoft Loopback Adapter", it will not show as NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback but as Ethernet Card.
            if (ni.Description.Equals("Microsoft Loopback Adapter", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                continue;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Seems unnecessary, you could ping to google at a time interval to check for internet connection.

Comment: pinging is unreliable which I've read maybe 15 posts on it saying not to use the ping method.

Comment: Then open a httpclient requesting its page and wait for the response.

Comment: Google is not the internet! And yes, pinging is not a great idea especially in a loop like this.

Comment: To be honest there's no reliable way to check for internet, you have to make a connection to a server and the server needs to be available. You should have a list of trusted servers that you believe are hard to be down like google or microsoft.

Comment: You can rely on windows api `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += (object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine(e.IsAvailable);`

Comment: @Kalten nailed it. And expanded as an answer it's what you should do. Add an event handler for the networks, when the change happens check what happened .